# Wordpress - 301 and 302 redirect

Tags: wordpress

I have this redirect error appearing on my WordPress website.

```
http:// www.worldofbanter.com/my-profile
301 Moved Permanently
http:// www.worldofbanter.com/my-profile/
302 Moved Temporarily
http:// www.worldofbanter.com/login/?reauth=1
200 OK
```

Any idea how to remove this?
Thanks

Comment: A common place where redirect is set is .htaccess file in apache server.

Comment: Yes looked at this and did not find any redirects listed

Comment: mmm could be set also in code, or via plugin, you can check in your theme if you have a wp_redirect somewhere.
You can check also if you have some plugin installed for seo, and check if there is this instruction.

Or ask to who built the website where is set this redirection.

Comment: I have SEO Yoast installed. All other pages are ok so seems odd its only this one page

Comment: Can anyone answer this question?

Comment: If you enter my website URL into this site if gives information about what is contained in the Header but I don't understand what I need to change: http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php